# How to dynamically create a sub-domain from a simple webpage?

Tags: php, subdomain

What is the best way to create the sub-domain automatically from PHP. I want to develop a application in php in which a user can automatically create a sub-domain from my domain if he/she fills the registration form sucessfully.

Comment: This will depend entirely on your server setup. Do you have admin privileges on your server?

Comment: yes i have full admin privilage and i am making the process of creating the sub-domain automatic. which we do from cpanel manually.

Answer (score 2):

1. Set up wildcard DNS for your subdomains (how you do this depends on your DNS server (or service provider)).
2. Configure your HTTP server so that your default virtual host will get everything from the wild carded DNS (how you do this depends on your HTTP server).
3. Pay attention to `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` in your script.

Comment: Just a note, you can perform step #2 using .htaccess or httpd.conf

Comment: You can't perform step 2 with `.htaccess` (the virtual host is selected before `.htaccess` files can be found). You might use `httpd.conf` but it depends on which HTTP server you are using.