# using a domain for specific account of another domain

Tags: javascript, extjs, cross-domain

Assume that there is a site (e.g. weblog.com) that users can register on it. after login, user1 would enter to "weblog.com/user1/" entrance page and then browse his own areas of the site. how can I allow him access to his area of my site through his domain (e.g. user1.com).

In other words, when other users enter to user1.com, we would authorize user1 in weblog.com in the background and users access to every user1 allowed pages through user1.com domain transparently.

note that if I use iframe to load weblog.com/user1/ into entrance page of user1.com, all links and also URLs used within javascripts redirect him to weblog.com/user1/. While I want this actions to be transparent from users of user1.com during working.

I am using Ext JS and .htaccess and CORS did not have any result for me until now.

every solutions, tricks or even subjects to study and keywords to search are welcomed.

Comment: Duplicate of [How to dynamically create a sub-domain from a simple webpage?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17595293/how-to-dynamically-create-a-sub-domain-from-a-simple-webpage) — there is no real difference between a sub-domain and a domain. You have to use some sort of server side technology for this.

Comment: weblog.com is my domain and user1.com is user's domain! I do not want to create sub-domain under my own domain. I want to assign a subset of my site to user's own domain

Comment: "weblog.com is my domain and user1.com is user's domain!" — That just means that you need to get the user to set up the DNS appropriately rather than doing it yourself.

Comment: "I do not want to create sub-domain under my own domain." — I said: *there is no real difference between a sub-domain and a domain*. That is still true.

Answer (score -1):

Sure. What you basically want to do is to rediect your user to there web in your sub domain.

1. Now, firstly you need to create a javascript that generates a weblog.com/user1 and so on pages on user registration.
2. Next you have to specify your user to set dns or you have to set it for them that will probably work through your DNS panel (A records, CNAME, or MX records.)
3. After the user has been authenticated to there site or your subdomain. They can access the page in the same manner but you also need to specify login script at the same time.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. This trick is usable for html files, but what about js files and json configs within them (e.g. "url: foo/bar.json" that points to a local address in weblog.com.)

Comment: You didn't specified that before. Well for that you can play with DNS if  you have guided throught it. Please go throught the above URL.

Comment: would you please explain it in some more details?

Comment: Ok check the above answer again.